# "could not receive data from server: Connection timed out" or "connection not open" errors when connecting to PostGres DB on a separate AWS instance

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 in my app server that is running on an AWS EC2 instance. I have my Postgres DB running on a separate EC2 instance but both instances are in the same security group.  When m Ruby code connects to the DB, it uses the Sequel ORM gem ( http://sequel.rubyforge.org/ ) .

Now, I have configured that Postgres 9.1.4 DB to be able to accept connections properly from the app server instance.

However, every now and then, I noticed on the app server's logs that it will have trouble connecting to the Postgres DB instance and I would see error messages like these :

```
PG::Error: could not receive data from server: Connection timed out
```

or

```
PG::Error: connection not open
```

So I went to the Postgres DB instance and looked in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log and I see a bunch of messages like these:

```
2012-11-07 08:15:17 UTC LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2012-11-07 08:15:17 UTC LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

I did searching around the web including stack overflow, and have made sure that my PostgreSQL does not have SSL enabled ( I have "ssl=off" inside my postgresql.conf file )

At this point, I am not exactly sure what exactly is the issue in the Postgres configuration. I do not what to mess with the maximum # of connections or maximum timeout values on my production server without a good proven reason.

The app server can connect to the DB most of the time, and this problem only shows up intermittently.

On the Ruby-side, this is the error trace for "connection not open" when making the Postgres call :

```
PG::Error: connection not open
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:145:in `async_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:145:in `block in execute_query'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb:33:in `log_yield'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:145:in `execute_query'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:132:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:111:in `check_disconnect_errors'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:132:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:372:in `_execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:234:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:379:in `check_database_errors'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:234:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:229:in `block in synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:105:in `hold'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:229:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:234:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:744:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:483:in `fetch_rows'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:785:in `primary_key_lookup'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:124:in `[]'
```

Similarly, this is the trace for "could not receive data from server" :

```
    PG::Error: could not receive data from server: Connection timed out
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:124:in `block'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:124:in `ensure in check_disconnect_errors'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:124:in `check_disconnect_errors'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:132:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:372:in `_execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:234:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:379:in `check_database_errors'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:234:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:229:in `block in synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:105:in `hold'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:229:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:234:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:744:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:483:in `fetch_rows'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:785:in `primary_key_lookup'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.38.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:124:in `[]'
```

I observed that if I have both the App server and the Postgres DB running on the same instance, then there are no connectivity issues, at least not yet. Maybe the Postgres is less lenient towards non-local DB connections?

Please let me know what I might have missed, I appreciate it!

IS

Comment: This would usually be connectivity issues. Is someone messing with your security groups and firewall rules? Is the connection between different availability groups / data centers, or is it within an availability group? If you monitor packet loss long term between the servers, is there much?

Comment: Hi Craig, no, only I have access to this production security group which contains only those EC2 instances (both on US-West-Oregon ) and I have not noticed any issues in connectivity between the two instances yet.

Comment: I am going to increase the logging for sure to get more detail on the server side.

Comment: As for this Sequel gem, based on the source code of the Postgres adapter : http://bit.ly/SO6FtR  , it is not clear immediately if it is using the libpq library. 

I also edited the original question and added the Ruby client-side error trace of the PG error on where it went wrong in the Sequel code, and it looks like maybe it did die due to a protocol synchronization problem with that error of "block_in_synchronize" on line 229 of sequel/database/connecting.rb 

Need to investigate more

Answer (score 2):

The usual explanation for this would be a connectivity problem.

Alternately, if it's not connectivity, it could be a protocol synchronisation issue. It looks like the two ends could be trying to read from the socket, with neither trying to write. So maybe the client is expecting the server to send a response, while the server is expecting the client to send data.

This will be very hard to debug if it's intermittent and occasional, as you can't really just tcpdump it and analyse it.

I'd add more logging on the server side - `log_statement = 'all'`, and a `log_line_prefix` that shows the client IP, backend start time & backend pid. That way you can start trying to match these failures back to the session activity that happened before the failure, work out if it's particular clients, particular jobs, or really just random.

Is this Sequel ORM gem using `libpq` at the bottom layer, or its own PostgreSQL protocol implementation? If the latter, that's probably going to turn out to be the culprit.

Update: It looks like it can use the `pg` gem (`libpq`-based), the `postgres` gem, or possibly `postgres-pr` (whatever that is). It'll prefer `pg` if it's installed.

Since it seems you're already using the `pg` gem, you're probably going to need to do some diagnostic work to track down where the problem arises - particular queries, particular clients, etc - and try to find a way to reproduce the issue. PostgreSQL's `csvlog` might be useful so you can load and analyse the logs more easily.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I did a "gem list" though and I only see pg (0.14.0)  , and not the postgres gem

Comment: @user1805458 I misread the stack trace; not used to Ruby and rushing. `postgres.rb` in the trace is `sequel/adapters/postgres.rb`, not the `postgres` gem. My mistake.

Comment: Btw, one other thing I noticed. If I had the Postgres DB and the Ruby App server running on the same EC2 instance, there are no such connectivity problems at all.

Comment: @user1805458 Sounds like you do need to monitor to make sure they don't have periods of packet loss, but also trace queries to see if there's an issue with protocol state management. See if you can narrow it down enough that you can tcpdump a session.

Comment: Just an update, still trying to collect useful info after doing log_statement = 'all' and log_line_prefix